# Issue with using one button to open/close in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to make a button that will open and close based on if it is clicked the first time - it opens, if the second time - it closes and resets.

Here is my code I have so far - it only opens and wont close:

```
var val;
$(".confirmed").click(function(){
    if (val == 1){
        hide(); 
    }
    val = 1;
    $(".confirmedtable").show();
    $(".searchconfirmed").show();
});

function hide(){

            $(".confirmedtable").hide();
            $(".searchconfirmed").hide();
            val = 0;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to put `return;` inside the `if` statement, after the `hide();` statement. - http://jsfiddle.net/bCPW7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".confirmed").click(function(){
    $(".confirmedtable, .searchconfirmed").toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5VYg5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the toggle() function in jquery to do this. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#div_to_show_hide').toggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

The toggle will show an element if it's currently hidden, and hide an element if it's currently shown.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `toggle()` based answers:

```
$('.confirmed').click(function(){
    $('.confirmedtable, .searchconfirmed')[$('.confirmedtable').is(':visible') ? 'hide' : 'show']();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/neu4k/).

It is, though, at best merely an alternative; the `toggle()` approach is more concise.